# Output of server host / domain

Tags: php

I've got a question, I'm using this code:

```
<?php
$actual_link = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
?>
```

This shows me the current link e.g.: `www.domain.com/en/page1`.
But it should output only domain and tld: `www.domain.com/`

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain that further? Why should it output something else?

Comment: Its for a "home" button

Comment: You can use $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] to get the server host name. It includes the domain and tld

Comment: Is it possible to get the language code as well? domain.com/en

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Answer (score 1):

With `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` you will get the domain.
With `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` you will get the folder tree structure on the point where you are.

Example URL: `127.0.0.1/PHP_learning/jumpletter/`

So in your case you write:

```
<?php
$actual_link = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
?>
```

Now you can cut your URL with the PHP `substr()` Function.

Here is an example:

```
<?php
$actual_link = substr($actual_link, 0, 15);
?>
```

Your new `$actual_link = 127.0.0.1/PHP_l`

So all in one here is your finished code:

```
<?php
$actual_link = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 0, 3);
?>
```

In your examples is the finished resault: `domain.com/en`

Should be worke fine. Enjoy ;)